# SharePoint Email Alerts

Tags: sharepoint, email, alerts

I'm having problem sending email alerts from a Discussion Board.

I've added all the work email to the Shared Service User profiles n SharePoint Central Administration area.

However, when I click on Alert Me I get the following error:

The following users do not have e-mail addresses specified: User Name. Alerts have been created successfully but these users will not receive e-mail notifications until valid e-mail addresses have been provided

Set my e-mail address...

Thanks to anyone who can help me...

Kash

Answer (score 2):

Please check the email Ids to the users in the Active Directory

After changing the email Ids you need to do a user profile import in SSP

Answer (score 0):

there is a timer job which sync user profile to site collection
http://blogs.technet.com/b/paulpaa/archive/2009/10/01/user-profile-information-not-updated-on-site-collection-s-people-and-group.aspx

Comment: If you believe this will answer his question, please give a summary of the site behind the link, as the contents may change or the site may go down.

Comment: There is a timer job which sync user profiles in SharePoint Central Administration to site collection,so it need to wait a period of time before user's profile(Email Address) synced to the site which you create alert.

Comment: I think you can understand my answer if you have some knowledge of SharePoint.I found stackoverflow is not very friendly to new user,especially for people whose first language isn't English.

Comment: yes,My English is not good,but I'm a good programmer,I can answer many people's question.I believe i can help many people,although my answer may has some syntax errors.